# Wanting to Handle POST to Node then stop processing

Tags: node.js, express

I've got an node app using express 4 that works great with a static public directory.  I want to have my jquery ajax call hit the server.js file, do some processing, then stop.  I can add code like this:

```
app.use( function( req, res, next ) {
    //next();
} );
```

or

```
 app.post('/rest/login',
    function(res,req) {
         // do some login processing
     }
```

but whether or not I call next(), I keep getting errors that say "Failed to lookup view "error".  My question is how can I cleanly get a POST processed from my jquery such that I don't get messed up in the routing of the app.

Comment: can you post the complete code in the app.post code block? I suspect your error is coming from in there

Comment: this is the full code block.  I set a debug point to test

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you remove the first option (the app.use) and only declare your route like this

```
app.post('/rest/login', function(req, res){
    res.send('this should show in the browser');
});
```